# I can't understand scheme define, lambda, let clearly

Tags: scheme

recently I started learning scheme language

but I really don't know how to solve this problem.

```
(define A
  (lambda()
    (let* ((x 2)
           (C (lambda (P)
                (let ((x 4))
                  (P))))
           (D (lambda ()
                x))
           (B (lambda ()
                (let ((x 3))
                  (C D)))))
      B)))
```

Q. What would be printed? How about shallow binding and deep binding?

I briefly understand define, lambda, let* but I have no idea to solve that problem.
How can I solve it? please comment with detailed explanation

Comment: Personally, I don't even remember what let or let* mean anymore, so I'll stay out of this discussion. But since the Michael Scott book covers so many languages, I'm thinking you might not have a Scheme interpreter on hand. This one looks nice: http://repl.it/languages/Scheme (just press Ctrl-Enter to evaluate your expressions) Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: If you are learning Scheme, I'd say it's worthwhile to install an nice, easy and complete environment such as http://racket-lang.org.

Comment: I already use mit-scheme on putty. But when i execute that code, it print value : a. I don't know why

Comment: What do you mean by 'how about shallow and deep binding'?

Comment: Ah, what would be printed if dynamic scope with shallow binding, and dynamic scope with deep binding in that code

Comment: @GoZoner I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure A returns the procedure B. So

```
(A)
```

returns

```
#<procedure:B>
```

If you want it to be executed, you have to run

```
((A))
```

which whill actually call B and return

```
2
```

So what is happening?
Calling B will call C with D as a parameter. C will therefore call D (bound to parameter P). D returns x so what is printed is whatever value is bound to x in procedure D. Since Scheme is lexically scoped, and D does not have any binding for x,  the binding of the lexical context is used, which comes from

```
(let* ((x 2)
```

which is why 2 gets printed, regardless of any other bindings to D that may exist in the other procedures.

Comment: Thank you for explain. But I'm little confused what "C will therefore call D (bound to parameter P)" means.

Comment: B calls C with a parameter, D, which inside C is bound to P. P is then called, so this actually calls D.